# Simulate checkbox highlight when hover over label

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a label that when I hover over it I want it to highlight a corresponding check box the same way as when you hover over the label attached to checkbox.

I tried using the mousehover sub without any luck, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

"Hover" in that context means when you move the mouse pointer over the control and then stop.  What you're actually talking about is doing something whenever the mouse pointer is over the control, whether it's moving or not.  In that case, you need to handle the MouseEnter event to activate the effect and the MouseLeave event to deactivate it.